# How to resolve this error? "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, opencv, importerror

I had python and opencv working until yesterday and right now I am not able to import OpenCV package.

**Things that I tried**

1. Checking whether OpenCV is there in the first place and is in the Path. Yes it is there and I got this snippet as output when I checked for it.

```
PS C:\Users\Koushkv> pip3 show opencv-python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.8.0.74
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Users\Koushkv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

2. I tried upgrading the OpenCV and it was already up-to date.
3. System Upgrade. I upgraded the windows and its in the latest release.

**Things that I did not try**

1. I did not uninstall and reinstall OpenCV because I wanted to be sure if I covered all the possibilities before doing this process. I actually integrated CUDA also along with OpenCV and since it was time taking process for me, I just wanted to make sure that I covered all the possibilities.

**Error that I am getting when I try to import OpenCV**

```
PS C:\Users\Koushkv> py
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Koushkv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "C:\Users\Koushkv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Koushkv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

Is uninstalling and reinstalling OpenCV the only option? I can't find any reason for it to not work all of a sudden.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of Python? Usually you'd want to use some sort of virtual environment/package manager to handle dependencies for you (anaconda etc.). Check if the `pip3` command points to the same interpreter as the one you're using to run the script

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your advice and checked the location of the `pip3` command by running the full path `(C:\Users\Koushkv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pip3.exe)` in my command prompt, and it worked. This confirms that the pip3 executable is present and functional in my Python installation and its the same interpreter as the one I am using to run the script.
I'll also explore setting up virtual environments to streamline my workflow. Appreciate your help!